# Regarding XenAPI Memory Issue

Tags: xen

I am developing a small client application for monitoring XenServer using XenAPI provided by citrix. I am able to get all the values(cpu,n/w read,n/w write, diskread,diskwrite...) but facing the below issue.

Can anybody please help me out in getting the memory (total,free,used) usage for the VM's present in the Xenserver using XenAPI. I tried the above by using **VM_guest_metrics** api call of VM, but its giving me the empty results. Please help me in this regard.

I have taken SDK(XenAPI) from the below link

http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Download+SDKs

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to get the data is to use the XAPI Round Robin Database (RRD) that comes with XAPI.

http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XAPI_RRDs

See also the tutorials from Xen Day:

http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Creating_a_LVM_backed_XFS_SR

In particular, the "Nuts and Bolts" session by Steven Maresca.

See also the code in OpenXenManager:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxenmanager/ as it is an open source clone of Citrix XenCenter and has performance graphs using XAPI.